# Log4J doesn't work and throws a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, log4j

I'm trying to understand log4j with few instructions given by my Java instructor. Here is what I did.

1) Created a Java Project and added some code in main method.

2) Added External jars (log4j-core-2.11.1.jar and log4j-api-2.11.1.jar

3) Added imports:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

4) Added the following inside my main class

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```

and this is where I'm stuck.

Exception I'm getting:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
at com.test.JavaProgram.<clinit>(JavaProgram.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
..
```

5) My instructor in the document also mentioned to add the following as part of the VM arguments and I did.

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./conf/log4j-console-config.xml
```

At the moment I don't have time to understand Log4j or eclipse. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: When I run the program as 'Run as Java Application' a window pops up ('Select Java Application') and asks me to input 'select type (? =any character ... ): 
When I click ok, the below gets display:

```
Usage: java 
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$CustomLogger className LEVEL1=intLevel1
       Where className is the fully qualified class name of the custom/extended logger
       to generate, followed by a space-separated list of custom log levels.
       For each custom log level, specify NAME=intLevel (without spaces).
```

I know Maven is simpler, but I'm forced to use this!

Comment: Problems with your step 2? Are you adding the jars to both your compile and runtime class paths?

Comment: This is what I did. Properties >> Java Build Path >> Libraries >> Add external Jars and added both the jars

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: Both Run as Java Application and Run Configurations doesn't work

Comment: @ernest_k, please help. I have to submit in 1 hour. Or else I'm screwed!

Comment: If your program is compiling successfully but failing with a CNFE at runtime, it's a question of incorrect class path configuration, unless your having a wrong or corrupted jar file. I suggest you look again at your build path, and check that the physical jar files have the class (which should be the case if the class is compiling)

Comment: Classes are there. I've edited my question to give you more information. Don't know if it helps. Please have a look.

Comment: @ernest_k any clue on what's wrong here?

Comment: It's hard to give clues with just the posted information... Is it your program that's printing that `Usage: java`? Have you tried right-clicking your main class, then "run as" -> "java application"?

Comment: I've added screenshots for you. Running the main class also throws the exception. What happens when I run the project as 'Run as Java application' is in the screenshots.

Comment: I don't see `com.test.JavaProgram` in the list on your screen shot. Which main class are you running?

Comment: I'm running the right class only. Trust me. In my project it has another name, I just changed the name while posting the question because exposing details of my code will be plagarism. Sorry man. I know how noobie this is. I can't help it!

Comment: Okay... so you're running the right class only, your class. And your class is not the one printing the `Usage` output. Yet you get the `Usage` output (which makes me think that the program doesn't continue execution), *and* you get the class not found exception... What is the problem here? This is not supposed to be complicated: add the jars to your eclipse project's build path, make sure the jars have the correct classes, run the right main class. If you get a CNFE, then you missed jars or jars are incorrect. If you get the usage output, you are running something you didn't write.

Comment: Aside: *"... because exposing details of my code will be plagiarism"* - Erm, no.  Plagiarism is when you copy someone else's work without attribution.  In your case, someone else would need to copy your code for you to be *complicit* in *their* plagiarism.   And, frankly, your instructors are not going to care if you and someone else have used the same package and class names for a program.

Comment: Ah! You're right. What I meant was, exposing my code in public forums is a violation of Academic Integrity. I wouldn't do that. And exposing packages or Class names is harmless. Agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use these simple steps. Just adding log4j to Pom.xml as dependency.
https://www.javatpoint.com/log4j-maven

Comment: Maven is simple. I know! But my instructor says maven is taught only next week. This needs to be done from this week.

Comment: Regardless, how can I convert my existing program to a Maven build?